# run vscode extension latex-workshop with --halt-on-error instead of --interaction=nonstopmode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I'm using `vscode` with the `latex-workshop` extension, and the compilation sometimes hangs when compiling `tikz` graphics.

[The FAQ](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/FAQ#with-tikz-builds-result-in-an-infinite-loop) recommends in this case:

> When builds result in an infinite loop with TikZ or other advanced packages, please replace -interaction=nonstopmode with -halt-on-error in your recipe.

But how do I do this? The recipes are not in `settings.json` but in `~/.vscode/extensions/james-yu.latex-workshop-8.23.0/package.json`, and I don't think I'm supposed to edit that directly?

What should I put in `settings.json` to change say the `latexmk` tool (which is called by the `latexmk` recipe if I understand correctly, see [here](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-recipes)) to `--halt-on-error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option can be modified from the setting in the settings.json:

```
latex-workshop.latex.magic.args
```

Or from the VSCode settings as can be seen in the picture below
[image]